# No datasource detection in Angular MatTable

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a problem with the datasource as I need to display a selectAll checkbox in the header of the table.

When I try to console.log the dataSource it returns an empty array, and dataSource.data-length returns zero.

I need an Input because the component is child of another component

```
<image-list [imageList]="imageList"></image-list>
```

I tried to put it in the ngOnit, but it doesn't work

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, OnDestroy, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { ImageModel } from "../image.model";
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';

export class ImageListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  
  @Input() imageList: ImageModel[];
  selection = new SelectionModel(true, [], true);
  selectionModelChanged = new BehaviorSubject([]);
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
  row: any;
  

  constructor(private builderService: BuilderService,
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any) {
    this._unsubscribeAll = new Subject();
    // this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.imageList); //it won't work here
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.imageListChange.unsubscribe();
    clearInterval(this.callLoop);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getImageList();
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.imageList);
    console.log(this.dataSource.data) // returns []
    this.imageListChange = this.builderService.imageRemoved$.subscribe(() => {
      this.getImageList();
    });

        
    
  }

  private getImageList() {
    this.builderService.getFinishedImagesList().then(response => {
      this.imageErrorMessage = null;
      this.imageList = response;
      console.log(response)
    }).catch(() => {
      this.imageErrorMessage = "Oops, there was an error getting the builds list.";
    });
  }

  markAsSelected(device: any): void {
    this.selection.isSelected(device);
}


/** Whether the number of selected elements matches the total number of rows. */
isAllSelected(): boolean {
  let numSelected = null;
  let numRows = null;
      numSelected = this.selectedImages.length;
      numRows = this.dataSource.data.length; //always zero so, select All won't work
  return numSelected === numRows; 
}
 
}
```

Thanks in advance for your response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should set an empty array when initializing the list.

```
@Input() imageList: ImageModel[] = [];
```